# Create Attribute to represent multiple sub attributes in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following type of code sample across one of my projects...

```
    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public DelegateCommand<object> OpenXCommand { get; private set; }
```

I am finding the attributes are adding a lot of "noise" to the code - I also see it in a way violating the DRY principle since I may have several properties like this in one class, all with the same attribute decoration.

**Q: Is there some way I can set up an attribute that will represent a combination of sub attributes?**

Ideally I would like something that looks like this..

```
    [MyStandardCommandAttribute]
    public DelegateCommand<object> OpenXCommand { get; private set; }
```

I have not implemented my own attributes before so I am unsure if this is possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you using to reflect the on the attributes?

Comment: BTW, you can combine the two attributes to a single line: `[Obfuscation(Exclude = true), UsedImplicitly]`.

Comment: @svick - thaks - I did not realize that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Your one attribute cannot "be" `Obfuscation` and `UsedImplicitly` at the same time (there's no multiple inheritance in C#).

Code looking for e.g. `UsedImplicitlyAttribute` has no way of knowing that `MyStandardCommandAttribute` is supposed to represent `UsedImplicitlyAttribute` (unless you control all of the code using all of these attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in C#.

But, if you control the places that read these attributes (with reflection), you can do it *by convention*.

For example, you can have a marker interface that will "annotate" your attribute with the attributes it proxies (sounds like a *meta-attribute*):

```
public interface AttributeProxy<T> 
  where T : Attribute {}

public class MyStandardCommandAttribute : 
  Attribute, 
  AttributeProxy<ObfuscationAttribute>, 
  AttributeProxy<UsedImplicitlyAttribute> {}
```

(Of course, you also have to match the right `AttributeUsage`s. And you can't set properties on the proxied attributes like this.)

Now, you could go a step further and use an IL manipulation library, like Mono.Cecil, to actually transfer the attributes appropriately in a post-compilation step. In this case, it would work even if it weren't you reflecting on these attributes.

**Update**: still in the reflect-your-own-attributes scenario, you can use the below code to get to proxied attributes, even setting properties values:

```
public interface IAttributeProxy {
  Attribute[] GetProxiedAttributes();
}

public class MyStandardCommandAttribute : Attribute, IAttributeProxy {
  public Attribute[] GetProxiedAttributes() {
    return new Attribute[] {
      new ObfuscationAttribute { Exclude = true },
      new UsedImplicitlyAttribute()
    };
  }
}
```

Use this extension method on your reflection code:

```
public static object[] GetCustomAttributesWithProxied(this MemberInfo self, bool inherit) {
  var attributes = self.GetCustomAttributes(inherit);
  return attributes.SelectMany(ExpandProxies).ToArray();
}

private static object[] ExpandProxies(object attribute) {
  if (attribute is IAttributeProxy) {
    return ((IAttributeProxy)attribute).GetProxiedAttributes().
      SelectMany(ExpandProxies).ToArray(); // don't create an endless loop with proxies!
  }
  else {
    return new object[] { attribute };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Jordao